GMC Canyon Transmission Change
I have a 2020 GMC Canyon and the recommended trans change is 45,000. I'm 15,000 miles over that time, should I change it or not?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

I'm assuming you mean the transmission fluid, not the transmission itself?

Better late than never. Change the fluid.
There's an "old" thought that automatic transmissions with old fluid in them have a bit of "stuff" built up on parts and when you change out the fluid, you get rid of the "stuff" which creates bigger gaps and such, which can end up ruining your transmission. The thought being that this "stuff" is somehow bridging the gaps and once removed it can be problematic. Some old school mechanics would suggest not to change out the fluid because of this. Your Canyon's transmission came from the factory with Dexron VI fluid, which is a full synthetic fluid. It lasts for a long time and produces much less of the "stuff" on parts, hard or soft. You should not see an issue with changing out the fluid, even though it's late. And believe me, 15k miles is just "barely" late in the grand scheme of things.

I'm assuming in my answer you are asking about the transmission fluid, not the transmission itself. The transmission itself is not a maintenance item, but the fluid is. If not abused, an automatic transmission should last for the life of the vehicle and may never need changed.

@Paulster2 It turns out that after visiting the dealer, I learned that my Canyon/GMC originally had a different type of fluid instead of Dexron VI in the transmission, which was probably causing the knocking and jerking. The specialized dealer I consulted mentioned that GMC is aware of this issue and advises dealers to flush the transmission and use Dexron VI fluid, which should resolve the minor jerking.. I was also, instructed to watch it for the next couple of hundred miles. I hope this solves it but we'll see
